# How to Iterate Through Cells in Excel in Selenium

Tags: apache-poi

I am using selenium webdriver to register my application..

[image]

Now I wanted take the values of username, password, confirm password, email and telephone number. I have used for loop to iterate this.. But when app grows, the fields are added more on the same page. I have to change again the limit value in for loop..

Can I use Iterator to check for a row, if the cell is empty, it should stop and control should be given to the testCase..

Can any one let me know how to use Iterator for this???

```
package com.xcha.selenium.utitlity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcel extends GlobalVariables {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static ArrayList readExcel(int rowcounter) throws IOException {

        XSSFWorkbook srcBook = new XSSFWorkbook("./prop.xlsx");
        XSSFSheet sourceSheet = srcBook.getSheetAt(0);
        int rownum = rowcounter;
        XSSFRow sourceRow = sourceSheet.getRow(rownum);
        int lastcellNum = sourceRow.getLastCellNum() - 1;
        int lastrowNum = sourceSheet.getLastRowNum() - 1;

        ArrayList<String> rowValues = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= lastcellNum; i++) {
            String val = (sourceRow.getCell(i)).getRichStringCellValue()
                    .getString();
            System.out.println(val);
            rowValues.add(val);
        }

        System.out.println("Printing Arraylist");
        for (String strVal : rowValues) {
            System.out.println(strVal);
        }
        return rowValues;

    }
}
```

Comment: I can help , once you share your code with question.

Comment: Shared the code.. I guess.. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: DO you using jxl method?

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI Documentation on iterating over Rows and Cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: @changan - I have created sample program to read data from excel using POI , if you need then I can share with you to get more idea.

Comment: Thank you...Can you please share??? shall i share my email addrss?